# Translate Silex routes

Tags: php, symfony, routes, translation, silex

I'm trying to make urls translatable in my Silex app.

First, I tried overriding `UrlGenerator` and `RedirectableUrlMatcher`, but that didn't really work.

Then, I tried overriding:

```
$app['route_class'] = 'My\Translatable\Route';
```

with code like this:

```
class Route extends Silex\Route
{
    public function setPattern($pattern)
    {
        return parent::setPattern(str_replace('admin', 'admin2', $pattern));
    }
}
```

But I'm getting https://gist.github.com/6c60ef4b2d8d6584eaa7.

What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you should try to create something like this $app['route_factory'] = new \My\Translatable\Route();?

btw. Can you tell us what part of code exactly is throwing this exception?

Comment: Why would I, it's already done in https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Application.php#L80, I will need this later if I want to inject translator. Please check my updated question for more details. Thanks.

Comment: I found the solution, here is a [short instruction](http://dev.umpirsky.com/silex-i18n-routing/) how to make routes translatable.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution is to extend RedirectableUrlMatcher and overwrite match method instead of Route.

Matcher.php

```
class Matcher extends Silex\RedirectableUrlMatcher
{
    public function match($pathInfo)
    {
        return parent::match(str_replace('/admin', '/', $pathInfo));
    }
}
```

app.php

```
$app['url_matcher'] = $app->share(function () use ($app) {
    return new Matcher($app['routes'], $app['request_context']);
});
```

Now when I'm accessing http://domain.com/admin silex returns content for http://domain.com/.
Hope this is what you need.

Comment: Not that it onlz returns content, but it also redirects to http://domain.com/, which s not good. I also want to be albe to generate this translated routes. That's why I tried to override `UrlGenerator` as well. Thanks.

Comment: This will not redirect you anywhere. Check 
http://norbert.silex.dev2.fsi.pl/
http://norbert.silex.dev2.fsi.pl/admin
same content, without redirection and I event dont have route ``/admin``
But you are right, to generate urls you need to overwritte ``UrlGenerator``

Comment: It does not redirect in your case because you have `/` and `/admin` routes, try changing your code to `return parent::match(str_replace('admin2', 'admin', $pathinfo));` and you will get redirects.

Comment: changed ``return parent::match(str_replace('/admin2', '/admin', $pathInfo));`` for controller ``$app->get('/admin' ...)`` and still without redirection when accessing http://norbert.silex.dev2.fsi.pl/admin2

Comment: Hm, yes, it works for controllers defined like `$app->get('/admin', function...`, but not for ones defined like `$this->mount('/admin', new AdminControllerProvider());`. Also, to reproduce redirects, you ned to try accessing non trailing slash url (e.g. `/admin2`, not `/admin2/`)

Comment: Hmm good point, I didn't know about it. So sorry, I think that I can't help you more with that now, maybe later :P

Comment: Heh, thank you very much for trying. I already tried this, but got stuck with url generator. Also, this approach is not good because you will need reverse translation which is not supported by Symfony translator compoenent. I thik perfect way would be to add it to `Route`, but looks like there is no easy way to override it on global level.